How many coin flips before heads has a 10 flip lead?
Coin Flip Runs
Trying to figure out an optimum gambling strategy where the win/loss outcome of every roll is 50/50.  If I’m using a laddering or martingale system on losses, I need to know how many rolls ‘on average’ it would take to get busted.
So equating this to a coin flip… how many flips ‘on average’ would you make before you’d expect heads (loser) to have a 10 flip advantage?
If I have a 10 loss bankroll, how long should I push my luck before statistically I’m at a disadvantage?  10 flips I’m sure I’m good because I only need to hit 1 tails out of 10 flips. But 1 million flips is too many because heads will definitely build a 10 flip lead somewhere in there. So what is the optimal number?
I’m not a stats guy. Not sure if this is a standard deviation question… or what. And not sure if this can even be answered.
Any help is appreciated
